# How to add Identity Scaffolding to an ASP.NET CORE Applicationon using Rider IDE

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, rider

I'm watching a tutorial about ASP.NET CORE Identity,In it the instructor add identity by scaffolding it using `Visual Studio`, but right now I'm using `Rider IDE` and i'm not seeing such option on it, so i believe is a exclusive feature of Visual Studio.
So is there a way to implement it on Rider IDE? or I'm forced to do it on Visual Studio and then come back to rider again?

Answer (score 2):

From the Terminal in Rider (default located at the bottom of the IDE) you can run the following commands ([Full Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=netcore-cli)).

`dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`

If you've already got the `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator` tool installed, you may need to update it:

`dotnet tool update -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`

Make sure you're switched in to the project directory if not already (not the solution root, `cd ProjectName`.

Then install the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` package either via the NuGet tab, or the command line (`dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`).

Then run the following to generate default project:

`dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity`

The Identity Area will be populated with both `Data` and `Pages` folders in your project.

A real world example (with an existing DbContext and using Sqlite) is:

`dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc ApplicationDbContext -gl -sqlite -f`

Answer (score 0):

Rider has that inside already, but first you get need to add `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`.
After that, there will be a file called `area`; right click on it and choose “Scaffold item” from the drop down. A
pop-up will appear; select “Identity” on the last option. You can follow from there.